# Rails 3 routing error with namespace and uncountable noun together

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces, restful-url

Well this is my first time doing this. In routes.rb I have the following:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :news
end
```

And I have this after rake routes:

```
admin_news_index GET /admin/news(.:format) admin/news#index
                 POST /admin/news(.:format) admin/news#create
  new_admin_news GET /admin/news/new(.:format) admin/news#new
 edit_admin_news GET /admin/news/:id/edit(.:format) admin/news#edit
      admin_news GET /admin/news/:id(.:format) admin/news#show
                 PUT /admin/news/:id(.:format) admin/news#update
                 DELETE /admin/news/:id(.:format) admin/news#destroy
```

As you can see the path to the action "new" is new_admin_news_path, unfortunately, when I visited that path, something pop up as follow:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/news", :id=>#<News id: nil, news_type_id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, views: nil, status: nil, start_date: nil, end_date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, news_key: nil>}
```

I was thinking that the "news" is an uncountable noun and this might be the problem. So I change the config/initializers/inflections.rb to:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep news )
end
```

Obviously, it is not working...

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: I use a very clumsy way to solve the problem, that is change the word news to "newse" as singular and newses as pular; set it in the inflections.rb as well. Then change both model and controller name. what a stupid solution! "Newse"!!! Any help to solve this problem?

Comment: Now I guess I found the real problem and find a way to solve it. Rails does not recognize the route of the form_for in that "new" template. The error message is really confusing.